# Program returned: 137 for Matrix Multiplication C++ Code

Tags: c++

I have written this C++ OpenMp Matrix Multiplication code that multiplies two 1000x1000  matrices. When I tried to dynamically allocate the arrays I got this weird error

> Program returned 137

I looked it up and saw that it was an out-of-memory error and tried fixing it but nothing worked.

I appreciate any help or advice on fixing this error!

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

double** fill_random(int rows, int cols )
{
    
    double** mat = new double* [rows]; //Allocate rows.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)

    {
        for( int j = 0;  j < cols; ++j)
        {
            mat[i] = new double[cols]();
            mat[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
       
    }
     return mat;
}


double** create_matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    double** mat = new double* [rows]; //Allocate rows.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        mat[i] = new double[cols](); //Allocate each row and zero initialize..
    }
    return mat;
}

void destroy_matrix(double** &mat, int rows)
{
    if (mat)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            delete[] mat[i]; //delete each row..
        }

        delete[] mat;  //delete the rows..
        mat = nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int rowsA = 1000;   // number of rows
    int colsA = 1000;   // number of columns
    double** matA = fill_random(rowsA, colsA);

    int rowsB = 1000;   // number of rows
    int colsB = 1000;   // number of columns
    double** matB = fill_random(rowsB, colsB);

    // Checking matrix multiplication qualification
    assert(colsA == rowsB);

    double** matC = create_matrix(rowsA, colsB);

    // measure the multiply only
    const auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // multiplication
    #pragma omp parallel for 

    for(int i = 0; i < rowsA; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < colsB; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < colsA; ++k) //ColsA..
            {
                matC[i][j] += matA[i][k] * matB[k][j];
            }
        }
        
    }

    const auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    const auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);

    std::cout << "Time taken by function: " << duration.count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;



    //Clean up..
    destroy_matrix(matA, rowsA);
    destroy_matrix(matB, rowsB);
    destroy_matrix(matC, rowsA);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to take some time to explain your `fill_random` function to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially when and where and how many allocations you do.

Comment: `mat[i] = new double[cols]();` is in the wrong place. For every row and column you allocate column doubles and you leak column -1 allocations for each row because you keep setting `mat[i]` to point to a new buffer.

Comment: Besides that, I also recommend you take some time to learn how to [debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use a debugger to catch possible crashes, and locate when and where in your code it happens, and examine variables and their values to make sure they seem okay.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
double** fill_random(int rows, int cols )
{
    
    double** mat = new double* [rows]; //Allocate rows.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        mat[i] = new double[cols];           // added
        for( int j = 0;  j < cols; ++j)
        {
            // mat[i] = new double[cols]();  // deleted
            mat[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
       
    }
     return mat;
}
```

In your fill_random, the allocation for row was placed in a wrong place. Take your main function as an example, we want this function first to `malloc(rows * sizeof(double*))` to store the pointers to row data, and the apply `rows` times for each row, with `malloc(cols * sizeof(double))`.

However, your code applies one column (memory for 1000 doubles) for every element in the column, without free them [(see: memory leak)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

In short, each time you call fill_random (with param rows = cols = 1000), `rows * (cols - 1) * (cols * sizeof(double)) = 999000 * sizeof(double)` bytes will be leaked, (the result cannot be correct btw), that's why you may get code 137.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can you show me what you would do to fix the memory leak in my code? I tried to fix it but I am stuck because nothing is working. I will select your answer also.

Comment: @Qi'ra your code is right for the most part, but `fill_matrix` mis-allocated too much memory inside the inner-for-loop (the line as I marked to be deleted). All you need to do is to delete that line and add a line in the outer-loop as I marked.

Comment: For example, when you are attempting to fill mat[2][0], you will allocate space for 1000 doubles -- some place in the memory -- and save their address to mat[2]. But when the inner loop goes to `j=1`, say, you are filling mat[2][1], the 1000 doubles' space is still reserved for your program, but you allocate for another 1000 doubles, when this allocation returns the address and save to mat[2], you will lose the previous address -- no way to release them unfortunately, and mat[2][0] is not the same element you previously assigned (&mat[2][0] changed)